# Sum float values at each index point in nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 3 strings:

```
["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]
```

and I have a list of lists which each contain 3 float values:

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]]
```

and I need to sum the inner list elements at each index point in the nested lists, and output this in the format:

```
[[0.5, "Apple"], [0.7, "Orange"], [0.9, "Pear"]]
```

I'm learning as I go, but this is beyond what I know so far. Any advice as to how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fruits, values = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"], [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]]
print zip(map(sum, zip(*values)), fruits)
# [(0.5, 'Apple'), (0.7, 'Orange'), (0.8999999999999999, 'Pear')]
```

In the above code,

```
zip(*values)
```

will get all the corresponding elements in the `values` list together. It will produce

```
[(0.1, 0.4), (0.2, 0.5), (0.3, 0.6)]
```

now, we can to add them, so we do

```
map(sum, zip(*values))
```

which finds the sum of all the corresponding elements in the `values` list. The result would be like this

```
[0.5, 0.7, 0.8999999999999999]
```

Now, all we have to do is to map it with the corresponding `fruits` so we simply `zip` it. That's it :-)

Since, you are using Python 3.x, where `zip` returns an iterator instead of a list, you need to get the list like this

```
list(zip(map(sum, zip(*values)), fruits))
```

If you want to do this without `zip` and `map`, you can use

```
result = []
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    total = 0
    for j in range(len(values)):
        total += values[j][i]
    result.append([total, fruits[i]])
print result
```

Comment: When I use the zip function in IDLE I get:
    `<zip object at 0x1044a33c8>`

Comment: This is perfect, I'll just need to study it for a bit. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Derpy Use the explanation I included in the answer.

Comment: Of course, I just had to wait for the timer to do so =)

Also, out of curiosity, is there another way to do this, perhaps a less efficient way? Theoretically I'm supposed to have done it without any knowledge of `map` or `zip`...

Comment: @Derpy Please check the updated answer, also learn the `map` and `zip` way.